# Please Help find Moka Pot Gasket Replacement

Tags: equipment, moka

I have a vintage Carlo Giannini Moka Pot. A family member mistakenly threw away the original rubber gasket. I'm not sure how to determine the number of cups in the moka pot.

Can someone please help me find a replacement gasket so I can start having proper coffee again.

[image: ge]

Answer (score 2):

We can’t give you shopping advice, it will depend on your location through which channels you can obtain a replacement part.

What we can help you with is to determine what size of pot you have - and based on that, you can pick the correct size.

- First, you can measure the diameter of the “no longer there” gasket, some web shops may actually list that value.
- If they simply sell by pot size, measure the amount of water that goes into the lower compartment. For my Bialetti models, the three-cup one takes about 140-150 ml, the six-cup around 300-310 ml. That translates to about 50 ml per cup (will be less after brewing, as some water will be absorbed by the grounds).

Answer (score 1):

Try piccolosgastronomica.com or email sales@piccolosnj.com. They have been very helpful in finding correct gaskets for my 80's Carlo Giannini pot.

Comment: This seems like an advertisement for the company. If you're a representative for the company please say so. Either way a more in depth response would be better.